# To modify a searchbox with extra css/jQuery options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

I am creating a search box query, with the following css animations, which is displayed in the snippet. It works like I need it to, but I just want to add two more things to it, to make it work for me.

1. How do I make the hit area of the search icon, expand the entire width of the header to make it more intuitive? At the moment, the hit area is fixed to the size ratio of the search icon.
2. I would also like to know, how do I display the search icon to the left of the placeholder text after it has been clicked?

Hope this makes sense

```js
$('.header').on('click', '.search-toggle', function(e) {
  var selector = $(this).data('selector');

  $(selector).toggleClass('show').find('.search-input').focus();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 2em auto 10em;
}

.header-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.header-nav:before,
.header-nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.header-nav:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu .text {
  color: #0097bf;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}


/* search icon */

.search-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.search-toggle::before,
.search-toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.search-toggle::before {
  border: 2px solid #0097bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
}

.search-toggle::after {
  height: 2px;
  width: 7px;
  background: #0097bf;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* x icon */

.search-toggle.active::before {
  width: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -1px;
  left: 4px;
}

.search-toggle.active::after {
  width: 12px;
  left: -1px;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#header-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header-2 .menu span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
}

#header-2 .menu span .text:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

#header-2 .search-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 2em;
  transform: translateX(20%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.3s;
}

#header-2 .search-box .search-input {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#header-2 .search-box .search-toggle {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#header-2.show .menu span {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0;
}

#header-2.show .search-box {
  width: calc(100% - 5em);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header-2" class="header">
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="search-button">
      <a href="#" class="search-toggle" data-selector="#header-2"></a>
    </div>
    <p class="menu">
      <span><span class="text">Search</span></span>
    </p>
    <form action="" class="search-box">
      <input type="text" class="text search-input" placeholder="Type here to search..." />
    </form>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can make full header 'clickable' to start search.

I placed the icon to the left where your left padding was, see if demo is what you need

```js
$('.header:not(.show)').on('click', '.header-nav', function(e) {
  var selector = $(this).find('.search-toggle').data('selector');

  $(selector).toggleClass('show').find('.search-input').focus();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 2em auto 10em;
}

.header-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.header-nav:before,
.header-nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.header-nav:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu .text {
  color: #0097bf;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.header.show .search-button{
  left: .3em; transition: all 500ms;
}

/* search icon */

.search-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.search-toggle::before,
.search-toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}


.search-toggle::before {
  border: 2px solid #0097bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
}

.search-toggle::after {
  height: 2px;
  width: 7px;
  background: #0097bf;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* x icon */

.search-toggle.active::before {
  width: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -1px;
  left: 4px;
}

.search-toggle.active::after {
  width: 12px;
  left: -1px;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#header-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header-2 .menu span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
}

#header-2 .menu span .text:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

#header-2 .search-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 2em;
  transform: translateX(20%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.3s;
}

#header-2 .search-box .search-input {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#header-2 .search-box .search-toggle {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#header-2.show .menu span {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0;
}

#header-2.show .search-box {
  width: calc(100% - 5em);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header-2" class="header">
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="search-button">
      <a href="#" class="search-toggle" data-selector="#header-2"></a>
    </div>
    <p class="menu">
      <span><span class="text">Search</span></span>
    </p>
    <form action="" class="search-box">
      <input type="text" class="text search-input" placeholder="Type here to search..." />
    </form>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I need to keep the x icon where it is though when you click the search the icon. After you click the search icon, it should be displayed to the left of the placeholder text.

Comment: I changed it,, now the icon is placed on left

Comment: that is nearly correct, but you didn't leave the 'X' icon to the right after it morphs from the search icon as well.